# Como alterar o valor do meta tag?

Tags: php, jquery, html-meta-tag

Estou tentando alterar o valor das tags meta com dados advindos do database porém eles não são preenchidos dentro das tags. O valor é recuperado normalmente e exibido dentro do script quando o view-source é ativado porém o content da tag meta continua vazio.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('meta[name="author"]').attr('content','Marcelo de Andrade');
    $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content','zzzzzzzzz');
    $('meta[name="keywords"]').attr('content','');

});
</script>

<meta name="author" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta property="og:title" content=""/>
<meta property="og:url" content=""/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('meta[name="author"]').attr('content','<?php echo $owner->name ?>');
        $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content','<?php echo $group->elevatorpitch ?>');
        $('meta[name="keywords"]').attr('content','<?php echo $group->tags ?>');
        $('meta[property="og:title"]').attr('content','<?php echo $group->name ?>');
        $('meta[property="og:url"]').attr('content','<?php echo ideas_url($group) ?>');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"View source" mostra o a resposta servida para a requisição HTTP. Não é possível alterar o conteúdo desta resposta utilizando uma linguagem client-side.

JavaScript altera o [DOM](http://tableless.com.br/tenha-o-dom/) que é a representação estrutural do documento. Você pode visualizar uma representação serializada do DOM através das ferramentas de desenvolvedor (F12 no Chrome, Firefox ou IE), onde verá que seus elementos `meta` possuem o `content` atualizado pelo JS.

---

Dito isto, vários crawlers não executam (ou executam limitadamente) JavaScript, então para fins de [SEO](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otimiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_para_motores_de_busca) é mais recomendado printar o conteúdo das meta tags direto no source original:

```
<meta name="author" content="<?php echo $owner->name ?>" />
...
```

Comment: Porém, ainda vale lembrar que o Google realiza o parser tanto do JavaScript quanto do CSS para saber o que acontece na página e para dar relevância. O próprio Matt Cutts já falou sobre isso aqui: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9BWbruCiDc

Comment: @RonnyAmarante sim, o Google funciona em cima de bruxaria. `;)` Brincadeiras aparte, eu ainda não tinha visto este vídeo, obrigado pela informação. `=]`

Comment: Obrigado, pessoal!